# How do I get the vertices of a defined area / region in google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polygon, reverse-geocoding, vertices

I'm trying to get the vertices of a region that's showing up in google.

For example here is the region of "Piñeiro" in Buenos Aires, Argentina:

[https://www.google.com.ar/maps/place/Piñeiro,+Provincia+de+Buenos+Aires/](https://www.google.com.ar/maps/place/Pi%C3%B1eiro,+Provincia+de+Buenos+Aires/)

and the here is the region for Kent in the United Kingdom:

https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Kent,+UK/

In both the region is recognized by google and shows up as a polygon on the map.

I want to get the vertices of that polygon without having to manually define or copy it myself.

The information I'm looking for would be a list of LatLng coordinates defining the polygon.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The polygons only show up when using Google Maps. They are not available through the Google Maps API or Google Places API.

If you look at the response format here: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#PlaceDetailsResponses. The geometry object only contains the location coordinate and view port.

```
"geometry" : {
     "location" : {
        "lat" : -33.866651,
        "lng" : 151.195827
     },
     "viewport" : {
        "northeast" : {
           "lat" : -33.8653881697085,
           "lng" : 151.1969739802915
        },
        "southwest" : {
           "lat" : -33.86808613029149,
           "lng" : 151.1942760197085
        }
     }
  }
```